# Not able to bind event on a new created element

Tags: jquery

here i am not able to bind the click event on my newly created html as    #topics-lists
my all other code is working properly except that this newly created element
this is my all js file i m using jquery 1.6 version

```
$('document').ready(function()
{

var val1;
var val2; 

$('#class-lists').find('a').click(function()
{
    val1=$(this).attr('data-class');
    $('#Varclass').attr('value',val1);
});

$('#subject-lists').find('a').click(function()
{
    val2=$(this).attr('data-subject');
    $('#Varsubject').attr('value',val2);
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/data/values/lists?standard='+val1+'&subject='+val2,function(data)
    {
          if(data.result=="Success")
          {
            var aa=[];
            $.each(data.topics,function(key,val){
              console.log(val);
                aa.push('<div class="ui-block-b" ><a data-topic="'+val+'" href="#subtopics" data-transition="slide"><div class="block-c">'+val+'</div></a></div>');

            });
            $('#topics-lists').html(aa.join(''));

          }

    });
});

$('#topics-lists').find('a').bind('click',function(){alert('hi');});


});
```

please help me to find way out of it
Thanks for your precious time

Comment: Did you know about `.val()` and `.data()`? No need to use `.attr()` for `value` and `data-*`!

Comment: The HTML that accompanies your Javascript is always helpful, as it gives a better view of how the code is supposed to interact with the elements, and the correct selectors to use.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to utilize the `live()` method. Check out http://api.jquery.com/live/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the event *after* adding them to the DOM, i.e.

```
...
if(data.result=="Success") {
...
    $('#topics-lists').html(aa.join(''));
    $('#topics-lists').find('a').unbind('click').bind('click',function(){alert('hi');});
}
..
```

OR you can use jQuery's live (which is deprecated as of in 1.7)